# Почему slick slider ширину слайда неправильно отсчитывает?

Tags: html, css, slider, slick.js

Привет!
Использую slick slider, и на разрешении больше 1920 он начинает неверно отсчитывать ширину слайдов.
Родительский блок имеет ширину 1369.910 пикселей, а ширина слайда 1370 пикселей.
Как это можно победить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не пойму, что все так Slick любят, его глючность известна и задокументирована https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Bug%3A+Confirmed%22

Comment: @drtvader Для того что бы разобраться надо ваш код увидеть

Comment: @labris, кстати подскажите, а какой тогда лучше слайдер использовать?  чтобы был хорошо задокументирован и можно было бы его использовать в npm пакетном менеджере.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan да там проблема была в том, что слайдер грузился раньше модального окна. И при прокрутке, высчитывал все норм.